# Channel form File Upload field

Tags: file-uploads, channel-form

When I use channel form File Upload field, it come together with the "Select an existing file" select box. Possible to take it away?

1 of the way is javascript to hide it.
but any better way to not generate the select box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the field settings for your file field simply uncheck the **Show Existing Files** checkbox.